# Stop the Enter Key from Firing on a WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

I have a basic custom dialog box for use with various controls in a WinForms application. The dialog looks like:

[image: The custom dialog]

For various reasons I do not want the user to have the ability to use the `Enter` key to select the 'Yes' option (`buttonYes`). Previously I did want this behaviour and I set the `AcceptButton` property of the Yes button (`buttonYes`) accordingly. I have scince removed this, setting `buttonYes`'s `AcceptButton` property to 'None', but the form still fires the `buttonYes.Click` event when the `Enter` key is pressed. I have also tried to handle the `KeyPress` or `KeyDown` events but these are not being fired when the `Enter` key is used. This is basic and annoying, has anyone come across this and what can I do to implement the functionality I want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fix this, set the `TabStop` property to `False` and use the code below:

```
private void form1_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Or, if as you say, you are not able to break at KeyPressEvent you need to handle ProcessKeyPreview

```
protected override bool ProcessKeyPreview(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
    int _ENTER = 13;

    if (m.Msg == _ENTER)
    {
        //Do nothing
    }
    return base.ProcessKeyPreview(ref m);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One thing: the delegate for the `KeyPress` event does not contain a definition for the argument `KeyEventArg`. Instead it would be `KeyPressEventArg` and the code would be `if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter) e.Handled = true;`. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Neither of these approaches have worked (I had tried the first previously). I had hopes for the second but this is not being fired either. I am confused by this...

Comment: @Killercam: Thanks for the corrections. Is your forms KeyPreview property set to true, if not pls set it.

Comment: I have tried that too. The `overridden` event above does not fire.

Comment: @Killercam: If it is placed in codebehind of dialogbox cs file, it must fire. Make sure you haven't placed it in the file which calls the dialogbox.

Comment: @Killercam: Similarly, the keypressevent should be in the cs of your custom dialogbox file and not in the file which calls (or initialzes) the dialogbox.

Comment: Ofcourse, I understand this. Thanks. There is obviously something very odd occurring...

Comment: @MoonKnight: Please don't accept an answer, that doesn't solve your problem. This one is jotted up by someone, that doesn't understand, what's going on. A [different answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36163872/1889329) to your question is a lot closer on target. Makes you wonder, why this answer received 6 up-votes, when it doesn't even work.

Comment: If you are using this in a textbox use if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter || e.KeyChar.ToString() == "\n") to stop cntl enter from working too

Answer (score 13):

All the answers here are wrong or have the wrong emphasis.

[image]

In order to understand what is going on you have to understand how Form.ShowDialog(...) is implemented, basically. Under the hood, ShowDialog is going into its own message loop. That message loop has hard-coded logic that treats the Enter key specially.

The dialog *isn't* closing because the OK button has focus, an enter press happens, and WinForms executes the OK button's click logic, which closes the window. The dialog is closing because the Enter press message is being plucked out of a message loop that is running on the top of the call stack, consumed, and causing ShowDialog to break out of its loop and close the window ... so you can't get the functionality you want by handling the key press events on the button; The key press event for Enter is never dispatched. The events going through KeyPreview are just another way of getting at the same events, and so this also doesn't help.

The only thing that works is to set the form's AcceptButton property to (none). The OK button can still have its DialogResult property set to OK so doing this will not break the dialog, but with AcceptButton set to none, WinForms just ignores Enter clicks from within ShowDialog.

Comment: THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER!! (jwezorek, i added an image to your answer, to make it easer for people to see & digest) hopefully, it'll get up-voted beyond the "accepted", wrong answer eventually, :-)

Comment: Even my answer is upvoted higher, I believe this is the correct method to be used.

Comment: Correct answer, on a side note, if your form that have a ElementHost with a WPF control inside, that control need to have it's own button "IsDefault" = false, else you get the same behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Also, if you want to ensure users will have to click on the buttons, instead of using the keyboard, you could set the `TabStop` property to `False` on the buttons.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Why not? He doesn't want the user to use the Enter key to select a button. If he set the TabStop on the buttons to false, he doesn't even need to care about the pressed keys.

Comment: Doesn't Tabstop only affect TabStop? What does Tabstop have to do with Enter?

Comment: Enter key is just submitting the button because it has the focus. If the buttons never get the focus they cannot be triggered by the keyboard.

Comment: Setting the `TabStop` property to `False` has caused the `KeyPress` event to come back to life!? I can now capture and handle this event and handel it accordingly. However, I would prefer not to have to do this. If I have not set the `AcceptButton` property I should not have to do this.

Comment: The event will be there, you just don't have to code anything to handle it as it won't press the buttons, cause they don't have the focus.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already changed the Accpet button property: what about form's KeyPreview property? Is it set to false or true? Maybe you set it to true somewhere along the way and forgot about it. 
Set it to false.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to deal with this and none of the solutions offered worked so I handle Click event like:

```
private void yes_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    if( e.Equals( EventArgs.Empty ) )
        return;  // ignore "Enter" key press

    // process mouse click...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the *.resx or *.ressources file.
Search for the `AcceptButton` property. It may have been set in one of these files.

Comment: why should he take a look at them?

Comment: Some properties are set in these files. He should clarify there haven't been set any of this properties.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Solution**
I tried many of the above solutions.  This is what worked for me.

In InitializeComponent, ensure that the AcceptButton is not set.
Delete, or comment out, this code:
// this.AcceptButton = this.btnClose;\

And on the button, add:
this.btnClose.TabStop = false;   (somebody mentioned this one above)

If that doesn't work, you can also try moving the focus off of the button, and to the window frame.
this.Focus()

Answer (score 0):

I try any methods to do this, but work for me one:

1. Delete AcceptButton.
2. Make a event for click on your button.
3. Write in event following code:

   this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;